# How to fetch all available databases from MySQL into comboBox control in C# win forms

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

Hi I have a application for retrieve data from MySQL database to some another database. I am developing this application in C# 4.0, VS 2010.

My query is when I install this application on some system having MySQL install I should get all the available databases in a `comboBox`.

What I have done for SQL Server is as below:

[image: Screen1]

Here in first `comboBox` we have option to select the MySQL. When I will select the MySQL I wish that the available instance of the database like `root` or something else should come in second `comboBox`. Lastly when we select the Database type as MySQL and Select the instance name, input the credentials we should get the database name of the all database in the 3rd `comboBox`.

How can we do this. I know in SQL server but no clue in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer.

here it is for all needy.cheers..

```
//Assign the all available credentials to the connection string variable.
        var myConnectionString = "SERVER=" + txtServer.Text + ";UID=" + txtName.Text + ";" + "pwd=" + txtPass.Text + ";";
        try
        {
            //if MySQL database selected.
        if (cmbDBType.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            cmbDataSource.Visible = false;
            txtServer.Visible = true;
            //Providing connection string.
            var connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            //command to select all database from MySQL
            command.CommandText = "SHOW DATABASES;";
            connection.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var row = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    row += reader.GetValue(i);
                //Adding the database in comboBox.
                cmbDatabase.Items.Add(row);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //if failed.
            MessageBox.Show(@"Connection Failed...Please check the credentials", @"Error");
        }
```